# Testng Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file

Tags: java, testng, classformaterror

We are getting following error while running testNG test case. We also tried with suggestion provided on site but it doesn't help us :

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/

Will debugging I can see these values in argument:

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType

file:/abc/xyz/123/abc/.m2/repository/javaee/javaee-api/6/javaee-api-6.jar

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1845)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType$1.run(AnnotationType.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType$1.run(AnnotationType.java:101)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(AnnotationType.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(AnnotationType.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.declaredAnnotations(Method.java:714)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:700)
    at org.testng.internal.annotations.JDK15AnnotationFinder.findAnnotation(JDK15AnnotationFinder.java:103)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:60)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:575)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:159)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:113)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you "tried with suggestion provided on site"?

Comment: I added javaee.jar in build class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding weblogic full client in project build path we are able to run the testNG TCs.

Comment: could you please say which jar you added to build path ? from where did you downloaded ?